# How does Orchard CustomProperties Part work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Literally I think the part will let me customize the property name of a specific content type in orchard. But when I attach this part to a newly created content type from the admin UI. All I got is 3 text fields with property names called "Custom One, Custom Two, Custom Three".

I couldn't find any examples from the web or from Orchard Source code explaining how should I work with it...

Comment: I don't understand, when you create a content type you choose a name. If you mean a content item, you can just use the title part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is obsolete. It used to be necessary for the List feature (also obsolete) to be able to sort on custom data. You should not be using that part.

Comment: thanks, i think part like this should better be removed from the source code on the coming Orchard 1.7